# Where does Xcode install if macOS is installed on an external drive?

Tags: hard-drive, install, xcode

I foolishly bought a Mac Mini with 128gb internal SSD for compiling Unity games for iOS, thinking "all I need to install is Xcode and Unity, and I can put documents on an external drive". However, macOS eats up about 45GB, Xcode will quickly eat up another 40GB and continue to grow without end, and Unity uses up a few more GB. You need about 40GB of free space to upgrade macOS and about 25GB of free space to upgrade Xcode, meaning that you quickly end up in a situation where there isn't enough free space on the Mac to upgrade anything. One time I cleared up exactly enough free space to upgrade macOS with nothing to spare, then the upgrade ran out of space and failed mid-upgrade (apparently the "required free space" is not accurate). This completely broke the OS and I had to erase everything and reinstall from scratch.

Having run into the "not enough space to upgrade" issue yet again, I'm ready to give up and try something different. Since macOS can be installed on an external drive, I'm thinking I'll reverse the usual strategy - I'll install the OS and applications on the external drive and save documents on the internal drive.

Normally Xcode can only be installed on the internal drive. If macOS is installed on an external drive, will xCode still be installed on the internal drive, or does it install to the same drive as macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps from the Mac App Store like Xcode install to `/Applications` which maps to the Applications folder on the data volume in the same container as the macOS installation. This can be moved wherever you desire after installation, but it sounds like this is the location you want anyway.

Xcode from developer.apple.com is the .app bundle inside a compressed archive. You can download, extract and move the app wherever you desire.

Comment: There's a lot more to Xcode than just the .app bundle. The Xcode cache can quickly grow to tens or even hundreds of gigabytes of files (e.g. device support files, simulators, compiled application bundles, etc). Moving Xcode in its entirety is somewhere between difficult and impossible; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159232/can-i-install-xcode-on-an-external-hard-drive-along-with-the-iphone-simulator-ap/59494802

Comment: @user Xcode is the app bundle. Its temporary files, archives when you build a project, etc., are not and should not be considered part of the app. For example, text documents or temporary files created with a word processor should not be considered part of the app bundle.

Comment: @user45623 Xcode also loads stuff elsewhere - in ~/Library and /Library.  But it does what you want.  Except for your projects, everything is on the boot disk.

Comment: @Gilby What I _want_ is to install Big Sur on the internal drive and put everything else on the external drive, but since this seems infeasible, I guess I'll do OS and apps on the external and documents on the internal.

Comment: @user45623 what is your drive configuration (types and sizes)?  I am guessing you have an internal HDD and an external SSD.

Comment: @Gilby 128gb internal SSD (not enough storage for macOS + Xcode; you won't have enough free space left to upgrade the OS or Xcode later), 1024gb external SSD.

Comment: @Gilby Added more context to the question. I didn't include the context originally because I was mostly asking out of curiosity and the context didn't seem important, but I guess the context could serve as warning to others.

Comment: @user45623 Sadly (for you) the 128GB internal is really just for basic use, not for developers (or app junkies). Yes, use an external (as fast as you can afford) for macOS and applications (including Xcode).

Comment: I don't use the Mac for developing. I do all my development on Windows and only use the Mac when I need to compile something for an Apple platform. For comparison, it would be no problem to fit Windows, Android Studio, and Unity on a 128GB drive in a Windows machine and have enough space left over for software/system updates.

Comment: Symbolic links are a mighty feature that let's you move almost everything somewhere else without the System complaining.